# twig how to modify template based on screen size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using symfony2, with twig and bootstrap3. I would like to change the way elements are organized in my template based on the screen size.

Here is what I would like to do :

```
{# ----------------------------------- LARGE SCREENS -------------------------- #}
            <div class="visible-lg-block">
                {# Emetteur et infos ticket #}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6" style="font-size: 12px">
                        {% include "AtgpTrackerBundle:Ticket:_viewEmitter.html.twig" %}
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6" style="font-size: 12px;">
                        {% include "AtgpTrackerBundle:Ticket:_viewTicketInfos.html.twig" %}
                    </div>    
                </div>
                    <hr style="padding-top: 0px">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        {# Tickets liés #}
                        {% if nblinks > 0 %}
                            {% include "AtgpTrackerBundle:Ticket:_viewLinks.html.twig" %}
                        {% endif %}

                        {# Fichiers associés #}
                        {% if files %}
                            {% include "AtgpTrackerBundle:Ticket:_viewFiles.html.twig" %}
                        {% endif %}

                        {# Description #}
                        {% include "AtgpTrackerBundle:Ticket:_viewDescription.html.twig" %}   

                        {# Progression #}
                        {% include "AtgpTrackerBundle:Ticket:_viewProgress.html.twig" %} 

                        {# Infos société #}            
                        {% if company %}
                            {% include "AtgpTrackerBundle:Ticket:_viewCompanyInfos.html.twig" %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>      

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {# Messagerie #}
                        {% include "AtgpTrackerBundle:Ticket:_viewMessenger.html.twig" %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        {# ----------------------------- SMALL SCREENS ---------------------- #}
            <div class="hidden-lg">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    {# Emetteur et infos ticket #}
                    {% include "AtgpTrackerBundle:Ticket:_viewEmitter.html.twig" %}
                    {% include "AtgpTrackerBundle:Ticket:_viewTicketInfos.html.twig" %}

                    {# Messagerie #}
                    {% include "AtgpTrackerBundle:Ticket:_viewMessenger.html.twig" %}

                    {# Tickets liés #}
                    {% if nblinks > 0 %}
                        {% include "AtgpTrackerBundle:Ticket:_viewLinks.html.twig" %}
                    {% endif %}

                    {# Fichiers associés #}
                    {% if files %}
                        {% include "AtgpTrackerBundle:Ticket:_viewFiles.html.twig" %}
                    {% endif %}

                    {# Description #}
                    {% include "AtgpTrackerBundle:Ticket:_viewDescription.html.twig" %}   

                    {# Progression #}
                    {% include "AtgpTrackerBundle:Ticket:_viewProgress.html.twig" %} 

                    {# Infos société #}            
                    {% if company %}
                        {% include "AtgpTrackerBundle:Ticket:_viewCompanyInfos.html.twig" %}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
```

As you can see, I'm using a bunch of includes which contain the blocks I would like to display.
I tried to use [bootstrap "visible" and "hidden" classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities), so that I can change the way blocks are organized within the page based on screen size.

However, my include blocks contain forms and accordions. So when I use a small screen, forms are not displayed and accordions don't work properly... I guess because they are already loaded in the "large screen" section.

Is there a way to work around this issue ? What are the methods I could use to do what I want ?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: maybe just use lil js snippet that will load proper version of  big.screens.php  lil.screen.php (axajed or reloaded whole page) ???

Comment: p.s. try to build 1 div for all screens, and some parts in them will or will not shows for some screens !  that all are usually do. or redirect is UserAgent is a mobileOS to lighter version of site !

Comment: Is there a bootstrap class I could add to delete for example a `<div class="col-md-6">` and it's `</div>` when screen size doesn't satisfy some conditions ?? (I mean, just delete the tag and not what's inside)
I know I could use unwrap() with JQuery but I would need to reload the page then.
Otherwise the best is probably to use separate templates and JS, but I would like to avoid reloading pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two choices:

1. JavaScript on-page detection, as per Vladmir's comment.
2. The [MobileDetectBundle](http://symfony.com/blog/meet-the-bundle-mobiledetectbundle) exists for this purpose. You need the `mobile_detector` service, which allows you to do this sort of thing in your controller:

   ```
   $device = $this->get('mobile_detect.mobile_detector');

   // basic device detection
   $device->isMobile();
   $device->isTablet();

   // fine-grained device detection
   $device->isIphone();
   $device->isIpad();
   $device->isSamsung();

   // device operating system
   $device->isIOS();
   $device->isAndroidOS();
   ```

   From there you can spit out desktop/mobile templates or pass the device type to a single template with conditionals:

   ```
   {% if not is_mobile() %}
   {# ----------------------------------- LARGE SCREENS -------------------------- #}
           <div class="visible-lg-block">
               {# Emetteur et infos ticket #}
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-6" style="font-size: 12px">
                       ...
   {% else %}
   {# ----------------------------- SMALL SCREENS ---------------------- #}
           <div class="hidden-lg">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                   {# Emetteur et infos ticket #}
                       ...
   {% endif %}
   ```

Personally I'd tend towards building one *good* responsive design, primarily using CSS.